# Why is the ODE linear?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking at initial value problems for ordinary differential equations.

Let $a,b, \ a<b, \ f: [a,b] \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ function and $y_0 \in \mathbb{R}$.

We are looking for a $y: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$(1)\left\{\begin{matrix}
y'(t)=f(t,y(t))\\ 
y(a)=y_0
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Each function $y \in C^{1}[a,b]$ that satisfies the differential equation of $(1)$ and the initial value $y(a)=y_0$ is called solution of the initial value problem $(1)$.

**Special case**

Let $f$ be a polynomial of degree $1$ as for $y$. Then the corresponding ODE is called linear, and the problem $(1)$ is written as:

$$(2)\left\{\begin{matrix}
y'(t)=p(t)y(t)+q(t), a \leq t \leq b\\ 
y(a)=y_0
\end{matrix}\right.$$

It holds that $deg_y q(t)< deg_y y(t)=1 \Rightarrow q(y)=\text{ constant }$, right?

But, if so then why is in this case the ODE linear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ODE is called linear because its homogeneous form
$$
y'(t) = p(t)y(t)
$$
(i.e. $q(t) \equiv 0$, and ignoring initial values for now) has the property that any linear combination of two solutions is also a solution. That is, solutions to the homogeneous problem satisfy the superposition principle.

In general, we call an ODE linear if setting the nonhomogeneous term, that is, the term that does not deal with $y$ or any of its derivatives, equal to zero makes the ODE a homogeneous linear ODE.

This is useful when studying the nonhomogeneous problem ($q(t)$ nonzero) because the general solution to the nonhomogeneous problem is given by a particular solution to the nonhomogeneous problem, plus the general solution to the homogeneous problem. And the homogeneous problem is typically relatively easy to solve, since one has the advantage that its solution space has the added structure of a vector space by the superposition principle.

Comment: neuguy Nice!!! Also doesn't it hold that $q(y)$ is always a constant? Or am I wrong?

Comment: It doesn't. The assumption is that $f$ is a polynomial of degree $1$ in for $y$, but the coefficients of the polynomial are allowed to be functions. For example, $f(t,y) = ty + t^2$ is allowed, with $q(t) = t^2$. (Your possible confusion: $q$ is a function of $t$, and does not take $y$ as an argument. It certainly isn't a polynomial in $y$, so its degree is not defined.) More generally $f$ could be a linear combination (with coefficients in the ring of smooth functions, say) of $y$ and its derivatives, plus a "constant" nonhomogeneous term $q(t)$ that is just a standalone function of $t$.

Comment: You said that: More generally f could be a linear combination (with coefficients in the ring of smooth functions, say) of y and its derivatives, plus a "constant" nonhomogeneous term q(t) that is just a standalone function of t.
$$$$
With that do you mean that $f$ can be written as $f(y,t)=a(t)*y(t)+b(t)*y'(t)+q(t)$ ? Or have I understood it wrong?

Comment: That's exactly right! And you can go to higher derivatives, like $f(y,t) = a_n(t)y^{(n)}(t) + a_{n-1}(t)y^{(n-1)}(t) + \cdots + a_1(t)y'(t) + a_0(t)y(t) + q(t)$. (I moved the $0$-th derivative term $a_0(t)y(t)$ over; in your equation it's $p(t)$.) $q$ can be thought of as the constant term in this affine combination, in the sense that it's constant in $y$ and its derivatives, but as a function $q(t)$ will generally not be constant in $t$.

Comment: A ok... but in our case we only have the sum $a_0(t)y(t)+q(t)$, right, neuguy ?

Comment: And something else.. Could you also take a look at this? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1157686/there-is-no-solution-of-the-ode-at-the-inteval-0-2

Comment: Actually in our case, if you move $y'$ over to the other side we have $-y'(t) +a_0(t)y(t) + q(t) = 0$, i.e. $a_1(t) = -1$. For first order equations one doesn't always do this, but for higher order systems it's customary to put $y$ and all of its derivatives on one side.

Comment: Nice!!! Thanks a lot!!! :-)