# There is no solution of the ODE at the inteval $[0,2]$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

According to my notes:

We take into consideration the initial value problem:

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
y'(t)=y^2, \ t \in [0,1]\\ 
y(0)=1
\end{matrix}\right.$$

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=y^2 \Rightarrow \frac{dy}{y^2}=dt \Rightarrow -\frac{1}{y}=t+c$$

$$y(0)=1 \Rightarrow -\frac{1}{c}=1 \Rightarrow c=-1$$

$$-\frac{1}{y}=t-1 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{y}=1-t \Rightarrow y(t)=\frac{1}{1-t}$$

Consequently $\not\exists $ solution in $[0,2]$.

We conclude that there is no solution in $[0,2]$ because of the fact that $f$ is not defined at the point $1$, right?

So solving the initial value problem do we deduce that there is a solution $\forall t \in \mathbb{R} \setminus{\{1\}}$ and so also at $[0,1)$?

Or have I understood it wrong?

Comment: Your work and conclusion seems fine.

Comment: @neuguy So the initial value problem doesn't have a solution, since $t \in [0,1]$, right?

Comment: Correct. If you look at $[0,1)$ then the issue goes away.

Comment: @neuguy Nice, thanks a lot!!! :-)